# Any reliable free resource to check the patent expiration of a particular drug?

Tags: databases, resources

Is there any database that is reliable and free preferably (though if academic access is needed, I can check that), to check when a particular drug patent expires?

Comment: No experience with this. I think this would be a two step process. Find what patents are linked to a drug then find the expiration date for the patent. I did find this link which may help with step one. https://www.wipo.int/pat-informed/en/